# DROOLS: Convert xlsx files to drl format

Tags: drools, kie

I've recently joined a team that uses a lot of XLSX files for their Drools rules.  Although they can be a lot easier to read than DRL files are and they can represent a lot of rules in a relatively compact space, xlsx files are not very conducive to proper source control, like text files are.

I would like to explore the possibility of converting the xlsx files to drl format for storage in our source control repositories, and possibly be able to convert them back to xlsx for viewing by our business types, that aren't technical enough to understand drl files.

Are there any tools that I could use for this?  Are there any methods / utils in the existing Drools API or Kie API that I could use for this?

Thanks in advance for your help!

I'm just in the initial investigatory phases.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to explore the possibility of converting the xlsx files to drl format for storage in our source control repositories, ...

You can use the `SpreadsheetCompiler` to convert the legacy decision tables into .drl files.

See these methods: https://github.com/kiegroup/drools/blob/81b4e30a0ebc119809d05cffc17be4834856516a/drools-decisiontables/src/main/java/org/drools/decisiontable/SpreadsheetCompiler.java#L84-L96

See this test: https://github.com/kiegroup/drools/blob/81b4e30a0ebc119809d05cffc17be4834856516a/drools-decisiontables/src/test/java/org/drools/decisiontable/SpreadsheetCompilerUnitTest.java#L801-L806

which converts this:

[image: decision table]

into this:

```
package org.drools.simple.candrink;
//generated from Decision Table
import org.kie.kogito.quickstart.*;
// rule values at A11, header at A6
rule "ID change_11"
    when
        $r: Result() $p: Person(age < 18)
    then
        $r.setValue( $p.getName() + " can NOT drink");
end

// rule values at A12, header at A6
rule "ID change_12"
    when
        $r: Result() $p: Person(age >= 18)
    then
        $r.setValue( $p.getName() + " can drink");
end
```

> and possibly be able to convert them back to xlsx for viewing by our business types, that aren't technical enough to understand drl files.

We did some experiment a while back for some, *limited*, support for this type of functionality and capabilities, but we did not publish it as it was limited to very specific cases, so currently there is no ootb support for this scenario.